# Temporary conversation not ending after ExternalContext.redirect()

Tags: java, jsf, seam, seam-conversation

I'm working in a project using Seam and JSF. For some reason (don't ask me, I don't know) the people before me decided to redirect the user to the response page through a FacesContext.getExternalContext().redirect(). The problem I'm seeing is that some pages, when redirected to themselves, never release the conversation (the conversationId is always the same in the URL). Has anyone had a similar problem? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

A conversation is not ended by a redirect. If you want to end a conversation manually, you need to call it by [`Conversation#end()`](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/1.2.0.PATCH1/api/org/jboss/seam/core/Conversation.html#end%28%29). You can also instruct it to end before a redirect by [`Conversation#endBeforeRedirect()`](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/1.2.0.PATCH1/api/org/jboss/seam/core/Conversation.html#endBeforeRedirect%28%29). There are more convenience methods as well.